# python modules vs organizational security requirements

Tags: python, security

I have a group of python developers who are asking to install xlrd and xlsxwriter modules so they can use them to read/write Excel Files.

The problem is my security team.  They will not authorize any module that sends requests and connections outside the server without proper authorization.

How do I test these two packages to prove to them that they do not talk to the internet?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these open source? If not, and your organization can afford it, you sign an NDA with the developer of the modules and they provide you with the sources. Then your security team is performing a security review on the code.

Comment: If your security team has a firewall installed then you could try using the modules and see them fail when trying to call home.

Comment: I am the author of XlsxWriter and it doesn't contain any code that sends requests of any type. The code is [fully available](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/tree/master/xlsxwriter) so you can verify that yourself if required.

Comment: @solarc, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @jmcnamara, thank you so much for stepping in and giving me that piece of info.  the security team couldn't argue anymore with your statement.  Most appreciated.  GREAT code by the way.